# Compare two ArrayList<obj> of different types based on common class property

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

I am in desperate need to find a way to compare two different classes with a similar class variable. I have two classes, one for a `Meter` and another for a `MeterRegister`. Both of the classes contain a serial number. I am using an `ArrayList` to store a list of `Meters` and a list of `MeterRegisters`. My end game is to be able to remove all of the `MeterRegisters` that do not match one of the `Meter` serial numbers. My question is how do you successfully do this by using an equals class method?

Below is my meter class

```
public class Meter {

private String meterID, meterDescription;
private Float serialNum;

public Meter(){

}

public Meter(String meterID, String meterDescription, Float serialNum) {
    this.meterDescription = meterDescription;
    this.meterID = meterID;
    this.serialNum = serialNum;
}

....getting setting.....

public boolean equals (Register o) {
    if(this.serialNum == o.serialNum);
}
}
```

Here is my Register class

```
public class Register {

int register;
String reference;
Float serialNum, phAEnergy, phBEnergy, phCEnergy;
String timeStamp, dateStamp;

public Register( int reg, String ref, Float serNum, Float phAEn, Float phBEn, Float phCEn, String time, String date) {
    this.register = reg;
    this.reference = ref;
    this.serialNum = serNum;
    this.phAEnergy = phAEn;
    this.phBEnergy = phBEn;
    this.phCEnergy = phCEn;
    this.timeStamp = time;
    this.dateStamp = date;
}

public Register() {

}

public float getSerial() {

    return serialNum;
}
}
```

Below is the method I am trying to use to take in two different lists and sort the lists

```
public LinkedList<Register> sortData(ArrayList<Meter> meterList, 
ArrayList<Register> unsortedRegisterList) throws IOException{

    LinkedList<Register> newRegisterList = new LinkedList<Register>();

    for(Meter m : meterList) {

        for(Register reg : unsortedRegisterList) {

            if(m.serialNum.equals(reg.serialNum)) {

                newRegisterList.add(reg);
            }

        }

    }

    LinkedList<Register> sortedRegisterList = new LinkedList<Register>();
    printToFile(newRegisterList.toString(), "newRegisterList.txt");
}
```

I'm printing to a .txt file because currently, that's the easiest way to check if I'm getting any relevant data that I'm trying to sort.

Thanks in advance,
BZ

Comment: Have you thought of using an interface?

Comment: That is a wrong use of equals. You want List.removeIf or similar

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to override `equals` for this. `equals` is for an equivalence relation between two objects of the same type.

Comment: just a note: the `equals` of first code is always returning `true`... remove the semi-colon after the `if` - also missing a `return false`, or, more indicated, just return the condition of the `if` (no ned to check if a boolean expression is `true` to return `true`, just return the (result of the) expression)

Comment: and `Float` to save a serial number can also be a bit of a problem - is the serial number a floating point number? and mixing `float` (primitive, all lowercase) with `Float` (Object) is also *strange*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Posting some code and vague requirements is *not* what you should do. Please clearly state what your code is actually doing, and what your expectations are.

Comment: I thought my post was thorough. I guess I'll have to repost with a more concise question.

Answer (score 3):

The `equals` method is defined on the class, hence it is used to check for equality of instances of that *same* class. For your need you can define a general purpose method which takes as input the two objects of different types and performs an ad-hoc equality check.

But if you have this need to compare two different types of objects, maybe they are trying to communicate to you that they should be the same, or related by inheritance.